# Getting a Responsive Full Width Image in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was having issues getting a header image to be full width on every device. I fixed this by changing the background size to 100%. Now there are black bars on the top and bottom of the image, separating the content from the image. What is the best way to fix this?

Here's my CSS:

```
//Color Pallette
$backgroundWhite: #d1d1d1
$spectrumRed: #a10019
$darkestGrey: #2f2f2f
$darkGrey: #252525
$grey: #6e6e6e

//Fonts
$raleway: 'Raleway', sans-serif
html,body
  overflow-x: hidden
  height: 100%
  margin: 0
  padding: 0

li
  font-family: $raleway
.container-fluid
  background-color: #333
  border-bottom: 4px solid $spectrumRed
#navbarItem:hover
  color: $backgroundWhite
#active
  background-color: $spectrumRed
  color: $backgroundWhite

.wide (THIS IS THE IMAGE CONTAINER DIV)
  margin-top: -60px
  background: #000 url("/img/9114.jpg") center center
  background-size: 100%
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  width: 100%
  height: 80%
  display: inline-block

#modelName
    background-color: $darkGrey
    color: $backgroundWhite
    width: 100%
    margin-top: -35px
    display: inline-block
    border-bottom: 10px solid $spectrumRed
#modelName h1
    font-family: $raleway
    font-weight: 600
```

And a screenshot of my issue:
[image: Screenshot of Issue]

Comment: `background-size: cover`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix. I set the height of the div to 0 and set the padding-top of the div to the aspect ratio of the image. That is just image height/image width. Mine personally came out to 52.08% on an image that is 1920/1000.

Answer (score 0):

You should use properties:

```
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
```

To achieve your 100% fully responsive image. You could always change your background size to:

```
background-size: content
```

for the tablet and mobile, but for the desktop it should be fine :)

Comment: My issue with background-size: cover. Is that when I view the image on a mobile device it will cut off most of the image and just the center remains in view.

Comment: @jacksons123 Then clearly you're going to be able to set the height to 80% as you have.

Comment: @Ouroborus is there a way to make the div height not being hard coded, but being dependent on the width of the div? Because if there isn't both a height and a width, then the image, of course, won't appear.

Comment: You can achieve this with padding or as a after of a parent div. There is many ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand properly your question, you have a full-width image , which will work on every device width .than width 100% will work properly. For this we have w-100 class in bootstrap. if it still not resolve, than fiddle your code , i'll have a look.. all the best